# TXT post to DocuSign always gives INVALID_MULTI_PART_REQUEST Boundary terminator not found error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm new to this and probably doing something very stupid, but if I carry on like this, I'll be bald!

As a test, I am just trying to send a TXT document for signing to DocuSign via a HTTP Post. I have followed the examples they give (I believe) but what ever I try, I get the same error.

Error:

```
"INVALID_MULTI_PART_REQUEST",
"message": "An error was found while parsing the multipart request. Boundary terminator '--AAAAA--' was not found in the request.
```

Ultimately I want to send base64 encoded PDFs but if I cannot even get TXTs to work...

I am using an XML scripting language specific to our in-house application to make the HTTP request, and the process has a diagnostic mode which can dump the request elements out to file to help sort issues: These TXT files are next and I have removed any sensitive data:

REQUESTHEADERS.TXT:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AAAAA  
Content-Length: 565  
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials>     <Username>myemail@myemail.com</Username><Password>mypassword</Password>  <IntegratorKey>mykey</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>  
Host: demo.docusign.net  
Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8  
Accept-Encoding: identity  
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)
```

REQUESTDATA.TXT

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit  
Content-Disposition: form-data  
{  
 "status":"created",  
 "emailSubject":"Test",  
 "emailBlurb":"This is a test",  
 "documents":[  
  {  
   "name":"test1.txt",  
   "documentId":"1",  
   "order":"1"  
  }  
 ],  
 "recipients":{  
  "signers":[  
   {  
    "email":"myemail@myemail.com",  
    "name":"Fred Blogs",  
    "recipientId":"1"  
   }  
  ]  
 }  
}  

--AAAAA  

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8  
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.txt";documentid=1  

Please sign this test document  

--AAAAA--
```

Please, if any one can tell me what is wrong I would be very grateful indeed!

Answer (score 1):

It's the formatting of the call, please take note on where I have line breaks and where I do not.

### Request

```
--AAAAA
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit  
Content-Disposition: form-data 

{
 "status":"created",  
 "emailSubject":"Test",  
 "emailBlurb":"This is a test",  
 "documents":[  
  {  
   "name":"test1.txt",  
   "documentId":"1",  
   "order":"1"  
  }  
 ],  
 "recipients":{  
  "signers":[  
   {  
    "email":"myemail@myemail.com",  
    "name":"Fred Blogs",  
    "recipientId":"1"  
   }  
  ]  
 }  
}  

--AAAAA
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8  
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.txt";documentid=1  

Please sign this test document  

--AAAAA--
```

### Response

```
{
  "envelopeId": "{envelopeId}",
  "uri": "/envelopes/{envelopeId}",
  "statusDateTime": "2015-02-27T18:53:39.5700000Z",
  "status": "created"
}
```